# Is it possible to undo setRangeText?

Tags: javascript, html

Using following snippet to insert text at cursor (works) but cannot undo insert using default keyboard undo menu item or keyboard shortcut.

```js
const insertAtCursor = (text: string) => {
    const element = document.activeElement as HTMLTextAreaElement
    const [start, end] = [element.selectionStart, element.selectionEnd]
    element.setRangeText(text, start, end, "end")
    const event = new Event("change", { bubbles: true })
    element.dispatchEvent(event)
    element.blur()
    element.focus()
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a programmatic change, so it's not part of the browser's "user-actions", that's also why you do have to fire the change event yourself (which should probably be in a timeout btw).

You can achieve what you wish with `document.execCommand("insertText", false, text)` which does ask the browser to pretend the user did this action and maintain the edit history, but note that `execCommand()` is currently not really appreciated by specs maintainers and browser vendors, though I don't think they'll remove support any time soon as that would break many websites.

```js
const insertAtCursor = (text) => {
  document.execCommand("insertText", false, text);
}
document.querySelector("button").onmousedown = evt => insertAtCursor(Math.random());
```

```html
<textarea contenteditable autofocus cols=50 rows=5>Select some text in here and then press the button</textarea>
<button>Do It</button>
```

Also note that I did add a `contenteditable` attribute to workaround [a Firefox weirdness](https://bugzil.la/1220696).